# Cloudfront serving javascript files as Mime type of Text/plain

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, https, mime-types

A Vue app being statically hosted on S3 is serving JS files properly through HTTP, but when the site is accessed through the linked CloudFront URL the app does not load because javascript is received from the server as text type. Are there any setting I can change to remedy this? Thank you so much if you can help.
index.html source in dist folder:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/inter.css" />
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.74e9a26f.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.cb99a641.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.7303d77a.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
```

[HTTP site directly to S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfqjk.png)

[Same settings but on cloudfront HTTPS link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ZZh.png)

Comment: Are you using Lambda@Edge by any chance?

Comment: no sir, definately not

Comment: Can you do a `head-object` and what does it show?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea...{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "2021-06-10T18:13:05+00:00",
    "ContentLength": 3202,
    "ETag": "\"a29ad9288c21e2c6a59014babf58c67a\"",
    "ContentType": "text/plain",
    "Metadata": {}....... so I guess maybe that's the problem then? how do I change the content type on a file within an bucket? and why does it work fine on the HTTP version?
}

Comment: yeah, this is exactly the problem. You can change the `Content-Type` in the S3 web console. Can you show the full HTTP request including the request header and request params?

Comment: I changed system-defined content type for javascript files to application/javascript, but they still came back as text type in the response. Request header: method: GET
:path: /assets/index.74e9a26f.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US
dnt: 1
if-modified-since: Thu...
if-none-match: "a29ad9288c21e2c6a59014babf58c67a"
origin: https://thankret.com
referer: same
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: script
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin

Comment: Have you invalidate the CF cache?

Comment: I believe so, plus I disabled then re-enabled the distro. I changed the content-type to "module", then re-evaluated. The HTTP link is serving still serving the files as application/javascript, but when I did another head-object on the cl it showed they have a type of 'module' now. Guess I should just wait a while and see if things change in a few hours maybe...

Comment: IT works now!!! wooo hoo. Thank you! My first Stack overflow question was a success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jellycsc solved my problem. I just had to manually change the system-defined content-type in the S3 console for the individual js objects from text/plain to application/javascript, then make sure the cache was invalidated and refreshed on my browser.